# Converting JSON to Interface type in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to convert a `JSON` into Interface Type in Typescript. Here is the `JSON` that I am referring to:

```
{
  Person: {
     createPerson: async () => true,
     updatePerson: async () => true
  }
}
```

Now, I came up with my own interface. I want to know if I am doing it correctly.

```
interface Persons {
   Person: {
      createPerson: Promise<boolean>,
      updatePerson: Promise<boolean>
   }
}
```

Comment: The code you have provided does not appear to be JSON.

Comment: There isn't any JSON in the code you posted. [JSON] is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array). The code you posted is code (not JSON) and represents a [Javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) (which is a completely different thing than JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code while technically correct, definitely has a room for improvement.

1) Firstly, you should create an interface for smaller entities. Here it is `Person`:

```
interface Person {

}
```

2) Now, regarding `Person`'s members, they are weird in your code. Keep in mind that the `Person` interface describes an *instance* of person entity. In other words, the interface should describe existing or created  person. Hence, `createPerson` member makes not much sense. However `updatePerson` is sort of ok, but there is no need to keep the "person" part there since we know the person context already. So it should be just `update`:

```
interface Person {
  update: () => Promise<boolean>
}
```

3) Now regarding `Persons`. There is no need to have such interface. Moreover, you can't have an interface representing an array of other interfaces. You can however create a *type alias*, if you want:

```
type Persons = Person[]
```

However most of the time using just `Person[]` is preferable, since it is a bit less abstraction.

Comment: That would mean that if I map it into an object for instance
const myObj: Person = {}; 
I would be able to do myObj.update = true?

Comment: More like: `const myObj: Person = {update() { /* your code here */ }}; myObj.update();` I suggest you to go through 5 min tutorial: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` keyword:

```
interface Persons {
    Person: {
        createPerson: Promise<boolean>,
        updatePerson: Promise<boolean>
    };
}

let person = {
    'Person': {
        createPerson: Promise.resolve(true),
        updatePerson: Promise.resolve(true)
    }
} as Persons; // <-- example of using as
```